# Use multiple dictionaries using hunspell in R

Tags: r, dictionary, hunspell, spelling

I'm observing strange behaviour when I choose different dictionaries in hunspell. I'd like my text to be spell checked in Australian English. but when I choose "en_AU" dictionary i get additional spelling errors that don't make sense.

```
> require(hunspell)
> hunspell("Couldn't be more delighted." , dict = "en_AU", ignore = dic_ignore)
[[1]]
[1] "Couldn"

> hunspell("Couldn't be more delighted." , dict = "en_US", ignore = dic_ignore)
[[1]]
character(0)
```

I don't understand why en_AU dictionary behaves this way.

How do I combine the two dictionaries?
My attempt to combine them doesn't work:

```
    #this doesn't work
    > reviews <-  reviews[, possible_errors_2 := hunspell(review_parsed, dict = c("en_US", "en_AU"), ignore = dic_ignore)]
Warning message:
In if (!file.exists(dict)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

---

Edit: I guess there are two nested questions involved: 1) why doesn't the first dictionary work properly? "Couldn't" is valid in Australian English <:{
2) is there a way to combine two dictionaries in R?

Comment: Your combining example has a typo, it should be `dict = c("en_AU", "en_US")`. I'm not voting to close just yet as fixing the typo does seem to make it work, but also gives a warning that suggests you're not supposed to pass multiple dictionaries to the function - not sure if the vector passed to `dict` *should* work.

Comment: that was silly.  I"ll edit

Answer (score 1):

As it is, hunspell doesn't support a vector of dictionaries. You could trace the get_dict function and add support https://github.com/ropensci/hunspell/pull/37/commits/da358a972d29c4bd39cf39755fc013a931bf3aba or you can combine your dictionaries files together.

```r
trace(hunspell:::get_dict, edit = TRUE)
 found <- file.exists(dict)
 if(!all(found)){
   dict[!found] <- sapply(paste0(sub("\\.(dic|aff)$", "", dict[!found]), ".dic"), find_in_dicpath)
 }
 normalizePath(dict, mustWork = TRUE)
```